# Aptana Search Project Ignoring Certain File Extensions

Tags: search, aptana

I've tried search for this but have been unable to find anything on this. Basically, I'd like to be able to search the project that I'm working on but only search files with certain file extensions. Currently it searches everything and this adds time to the search that will never return results for what I'm looking for. Is there a way to do this or am I just out of luck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your search dialog not look like this?

[image]

`Ctrl + H` or Search > Search will bring up this dialog which allows you to put in a file name pattern to limit your search... what are you doing?

Comment: I was trying to do it directly from the app explorer which doesn't have these options. Sorry should of clarified.

Comment: Yeah, you don't really have any options with that search as far as limiting file types (unless you are searching for a given file name rather than by contents). Then you could change the search to file name and use a regular expression.